# Rails, Paperclip, S3, undefined method 'size'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

I am using

```
ruby 2.2.0
paperclip (4.3.2)
aws-sdk (1.66.0)
```

when trying to upload a file to AWS S3 I get the following error

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `size' for nil:NilClass:
  paperclip (4.3.2) lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:466:in `reset_file_if_original_reprocessed'
  paperclip (4.3.2) lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:110:in `assign'
  paperclip (4.3.2) lib/paperclip/has_attached_file.rb:66:in `block in define_setter'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:54:in `_assign_attribute'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:41:in `block in assign_attributes'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb:183:in `each_pair'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:35:in `assign_attributes'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:249:in `block in update'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:347:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `block in transaction'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:188:in `within_new_transaction'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `transaction'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:220:in `transaction'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:344:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:248:in `update'
```

This error seems very odd to me, because the upload to S3 works and the file gets stored there:

```
[paperclip] saving /users/2/identity_documents/xxx.PDF
[AWS S3 200 0.768066 0 retries] put_object(:acl=>:private,:bucket_name=>"imp-staging",:content_length=>167130,:content_type=>"application/pdf",:data=>Paperclip::UploadedFileAdapter: xxx.PDF,:key=>"users/2/identity_documents/xxx.PDF")
```

I also noticed, that `@queued_for_write` within the class `Attachment` is empty.

Anybody observed the same behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this problem on my own after sifting through all related Paperclip issues.

I was using a `after_*_post_process` callback for updating my model after uploading the document. It seems like there is a problem when trying to `save` the model within this callback so I switched to `update_column` and everything works as expected.

Comment: Switching from `update_attributes` to `update_column(s)` fixed the issue for me. It seems the issue here is fixed by not triggering additional callbacks from inside the `after_post_process` hook. Thanks for the fix!